# How to make vim detect <C-LeftMouse> with konsole terminal?

Tags: vim, neovim, konsole

With gvim, I can map `<C-LeftMouse>`, but I can't with vim running inside a terminal emulator (konsole in my case).

I have reasons to think it's because the sequence <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + **CLICK** is not sent/detected :

in insert mode, typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + **CLICK** prints "" with gvim, but only "" with konsole.

how to make vim / neovim to recognize this (useful) combination ?

**EDIT Note that I already `set mouse=a` in vim**

Answer (score 0):

in the terminal you have to *enable* the mouse:

```
set mouse=a

map <C-LeftMouse> :echo 'Hello Left'<CR>
map <C-RightMouse> :echo 'Hello Right'<CR>
```

see `:help mouse`

Comment: I forgot to precise `mouse` is already set to `a`...

Comment: @hl037_ oops, I'm sorry, I assumed you missed that step. can you show the exact mapping that isn't working? have you tried with simple "hello world" like the one in the answer? than can you try running `vim --clean` (it will not read vimrc) and then type `:set mouse=a` and the mapping? lastly it may be that the combination is used by your terminal emulator and gets intercepted before it can reach vim. can you try with another mapping that involves the mouse but not Ctrl like `map <LeftMouse> :echo 'Hello LeftMouse'<CR>`?

Comment: I think this is not a vim problem but a Konsole problem : in insert mode, when I hit <C-v><C-LeftMouse>, only "<LeftMouse>" is printed (in gvim, when I do the same, <C-LeftMouse> is rightly printed).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. My solution is to bind it to `<2-LeftMouse>`. By default double click will select a word but I never use this, so I bind double click to my jedi-vim's jump to definition.